# How to clone Ubuntu server via .iso for bootable usb?

Tags: server, usb, iso, clone

I am trying to clone whole Ubuntu system(server) to another. It can be done via backing up hard disk. But, Can it possible to make iso for making a clone to make bootable usb?

Comment: Many downstream projects based on Ubuntu have created scripts to do that; eg. Makulu wrote one for their own project which clones an existing system (it was built for desktop, but is run from terminal, and being open source could always be tweaked)

Answer (score 0):

I always use clonezilla. It is best to make copies as well as to clone.
You simply download the .iso from clonezilla on a usb and you need a hard disk connected by usb to the computer or another usb to make the copy. The size will depend on how much information you have on your device.